# How to display message for 3 seconds in javascript

Tags: javascript, settimeout

```
setTimeout(function(){
     document.getElementById("alarmmsg").innerHTML=msg;
     },3000);
```

Above code is displaying message but not going off screen. What could be the problem?

Comment: Your function waits 3 sec and then shows the message. Now you need on to remove it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

First display the message, then after 3 seconds delete it.

```
document.getElementById("alarmmsg").innerHTML = msg;

setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById("alarmmsg").innerHTML = '';
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 2):

You never remove it from the element; you're simply telling the browser to wait 3s and then set the `innerHTML` of `alarmmsg` to your variable.

```
setTimeout(function () {
    document.getElementById("alarmmsg").innerHTML = msg;
}, 3000);

// Now remove alarmmsg's content.
document.getElementById("alarmmsg").innerHTML = "";
```

Comment: That will wait 300ms (not 3 seconds) before displaying the message, then immediately remove it per your `innerHTML = ''`. All in the blink of an eye.

Comment: All it requires is an extra zero. Edited to suit.